# require.js project optimization: can't find the dir value

Tags: build, requirejs, gruntjs

Here is my project folder structure：

```
project
|--Gruntfile.js
|--build
|--public
|--|--js
|-----|--lib
|-----|--module
|-----|--main.js
```

my build config is in the `Gruntfile.js`

```
    requirejs: {
        compileProject: {
            baseUrl: 'js', 
            appDir: 'public', 
            dir: 'build',
            modules: [
                { name: 'main'}
            ],
            paths: {
                main: 'main',
                jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.10.0.min.js'
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I run it, the terminal tell me wrong:

> Running "requirejs:compileProject" (requirejs) task
>   [Error: Error: Missing either an "out" or "dir" config value. If using "appDir" for a full project optimization, use "dir". If you want to optimize to one file, use "out".

however I have already set the `dir` value, so what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your requirejs options should be specified within `options`:

```
requirejs: {
    compileProject: {
        options : {
            baseUrl: 'js', 
            appDir: 'public', 
            dir: 'build',
            modules: [
                { name: 'main'}
            ],
            paths: {
                main: 'main',
                jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.10.0.min.js'
            }
        }
    }
}
```